# Magento connect stucks at Checking dependencies of packages

Tags: magento-1.9

when ever I try to install some extension magento connect stuck at: 
Checking dependencies of packages
and nothing else is shown after even waiting for hours. Any suggestion please.!

Answer (score 0):

When you install extension in magento is very important that you follow two simple steps

First Step: Disable the cache;
Second step: Go in system-> tool -> compilation and disable the compilation

Then install your extension and if anything is ok, go in admin panel, logout and login then, enable cache and compilation again. 
If you have other error maybe your extension not is compatible with your magento version or there is some error in this extesion... Anyway try this suggestion because it works. If my helped works for you please left a flag in this answer. response.

Comment: yes cache and compilation is disabled. Actually I can't see further anything from 
Checking dependencies of packages
but works well when I uninstall any plugin.

Comment: So is in conflict with any plugin.... try to install your extension and then install one by one the other plugins and try to understand what plugin is in conflit!!! Don't forget to clean and refresh the cache for every single operation.